# How to add a textview with background image at the bottom of the navigation drawer?

Tags: android

I need to set a textview with background image at the bottom part of the navigation drawer. I am unable to do it from xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:-

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/side_menu_bg_color"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_mains"
    app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavigationDrawer"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/White"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    app:selectableItemBackground="@drawable/nav_drawer_item_selector">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/nav_bar_playback_controls" /> // This is bottom layout with black background and 2 textviews
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

nav_bar_playback_controls.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/Black"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/artist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:text="Demo text"
        android:textSize="23px"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/artist"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/play_pause"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="Hello there"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="31px"
        android:textStyle="bold|normal"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/play_pause"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:padding="8dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I tried this and it works perfectly, thanks. But, it ovverides my navigation drawer items, is it possible to implement that text at the very bottom (scrollable) like an item so the user could see this when they scroll at the bottom of the page?

Comment: @Arda Çebi: Well in that case you can put your navigation drawer items in listview or recyclerview ,then your bottom, put both of these views in relative layout, apply layout above or below property using Relative layout. This trick will not override menu items and user could see this properly.

Comment: if possible, is it possible for you to create a gist (with example items etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your activity_main.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
    <include layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:layout_above="@+id/llBottomLay"
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llBottomLay"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:background="#e6e6e6"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <!--place your things here-->
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

* LinearLayout of id *llBottomLay* need to replace by Relative or other option depending your need

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    ...removed for brevity...
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    <TextView 
    ...your required properties...
       android:gravity="bottom" android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
</merge>
```